# Is there any browser that allows to view the source?

Tags: browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I view source in the Android browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-view-source-in-the-android-browser)

I miss this feature. How to do that? Is it possible with the default browser?