# Another way for debugging web sites/apps using Android

Tags: applications

Nowadays I miss my laptop I have only my Note 10.1 Android Running 4.4.2 ... is there any way to view web page source or open console or that developer options that we do using our normal laptop ?

Comment: See [How do I view source in the Android browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5039)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View source code of web page in Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137015/view-source-code-of-web-page-in-android)